# How to return user input values (double) from EditText- Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm new to OOP, but I've had experience with C previously. I'm learning Java and working on building an app slowly. I find I learn more when I apply what I've read and learned from other sources to projects.

The problem I've been facing for a while now is in regard to returning values users have inputted into EditText fields and using those values to run some calculations. Here is my code:

```
public class Linmotion extends Activity {
// Creating the variables
EditText time, acc, dis, ivel, fvel;
Button solve;
int count = 0;
double time1,acc1,dis1,ivel1,fvel1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_linmotion1);

    time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    acc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    dis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
    ivel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
    fvel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText05);
    solve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSolve);

    //Trying to return inputted values
    /*
    if (!(time.getText() == null)) {
        time1=Double.parseDouble(time.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!(acc.getText()==null)){
        acc1=Double.parseDouble(acc.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!(ivel.getText()==null)){
        ivel1=Double.parseDouble(ivel.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!(fvel.getText()==null)){
        fvel1=Double.parseDouble(fvel.getText().toString());
    }s
    if(!(dis.getText()==null)){
        dis1=Double.parseDouble(dis.getText().toString());
    }
    /*
     * Double.parseDouble(time.getText().toString());
     * Double.parseDouble(acc.getText().toString());
     * Double.parseDouble(ivel.getText().toString());
     * Double.parseDouble(fvel.getText().toString());
     * Double.parseDouble(dis.getText().toString());
     */



    // add button listener
    solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (time1 < 0) {
                count++;
                if (acc1 < 0) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (ivel1 < 0) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (fvel1 < 0) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (dis1 < 0) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 2) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Linmotion.this);
                    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                    alert.show();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Please input values into at least 3 fields");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                // function of dialog button

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    alert.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                }

            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.linmotion, menu);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

The if statements and the other Double.parseDouble lines have been commented out because every time I try to debug the code the app crashes the instant Linmotion is created. I suspect its from the fact that onCreate runs the Double.parseDouble code and the values in the field are null. I tried to fix this with the if statements and it still crashes. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Again, if I wasn't clear I just want the values inputted into the EditText to return a double and then use that double in the Java code to run some equations and an alert dialog if not enough fields have been filled in.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I finally figured out what was wrong with my code. I took in advice from everyone and revised accordingly, so here it is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_linmotion1);

    time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTexttime);
    acc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextacc);
    dis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextdis);
    ivel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextivel);
    fvel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextfvel);
    solve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSolve);    
    solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count=0;
            if (time.getText().toString().equals("")){
                count++;
            }
                    if(dis.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        count++;
                    }
                        if(fvel.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            count++;
                        }
                            if(ivel.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                count++;
                            }
                                if(acc.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                    count++;
                                }

            if (count>2){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final AlertDialog alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(Linmotion.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Oops");
            alert.setMessage("Please input values in at least 3 fields.");
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    alert.cancel();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            count=0;
        }
            if(!(time.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                time1=Double.parseDouble(time.getText().toString());

            }
            if(!(acc.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                acc1=Double.parseDouble(acc.getText().toString());

            }
            if(!(dis.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                dis1=Double.parseDouble(dis.getText().toString());

            }
            if(!(ivel.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                ivel1=Double.parseDouble(ivel.getText().toString());

            }
            if(!(fvel.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                fvel1=Double.parseDouble(fvel.getText().toString());

            }


        }       });



}
```

In regard to the issues I had with the alertdialog I realized that my count integer would continue to increase every time the solve button was clicked. To fix this I simply equaled the integer to 0 at the beginning of the onclicklistener and at the end of the if statement regarding the dialog. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you also post your error stack?

Comment: 1 - You need to move your parsing code to the OnClickListener of the solve button.
2 - You should either wrap your parsing code in try - catch blocks or do some validation before you attempt to parse them.

Comment: I'm looking at these replies and comments carefully and I've revised my code accordingly. The good news is that my app doesn't crash anymore, but I've still haven't been able to make the dialog appear when not enough fields have been entered. My solve button does virtually nothing when I press it with only 2 fields filled in (I need atleast 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from an `EditText` using `getText()`..

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) for more details

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) `getText()` returns an Editable.

so,

```
time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
String value = time.getText().toString();
```

Now, as i've said earlier, since `getText()` returns an `Editable` you need to convert it into `String` before you use it..

So, change

```
if (!(time.getText() == null)) {
```

to

```
if (!(time.getText().toString() == null)) {
```

Also, if you want to check if the `EditText` is empty or not, try like this..

```
if (!(time.getText().toString() .equals(""))) {
```

Try this answer..

Comment: Had this problem few times. It is not hard to forget that EditText::getText() returns Editable instead of String.

Comment: silly, but can create problems..:D @LukaszIzmajlowicz

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're doing it right. I think the problem might be that it's in your OnCreate method.

Try making the Button `Solve`'s OnClick method run your commented code before doing the logic!

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you are trying to read these text fields on creation. This is not what you want to do.

You are trying to access the EditTexts before the page finishes loading. Instead, you need to do this in an event handler, like you have for the buttons. Read the values in an event handler, not in onCreate.

The simplest option would be to add an "update" button and do all those operations in the onClick handler for that button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a Listener. Because onCreate() is called when the Actvity first start. This means that you can't get the text from your EditTexts because the Actvity is creating. But you can use your OnClickListener or other Listeners. You can easily write your commented lines to the OnClickListener. At the time you are clicking the button the method getText().toString() return the values. If you want to do it without clicking on a button use addTextOnChangedListener() on yout EditText.

Answer (score 0):

`Oncreate` is the first method called when an activity is created, so by the time the `onCreate` is called, the `editText` is having an empty string which you are giving as an input to `parseDouble` which will give `NumberFormatException`.

You can avoid this crash by putting a button and handling the button `onClick` event. Inside this button click you collect the values from `editfield`. You can handle on click by defining listeners in the following way

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="yourHandlerName" />
```

Now define your  `onClick` with `getText` to get text from `editfield` in the following way

```
public void yourHandlerName(View v) {
    switch(v.getid()) {
      case R.id.mybutton: Double.parseDouble(editField.getText().to string());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `EditText` fields initially contain text, that cannot be parsed with [`Double.parseDouble`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) (Something like the empty string). A `NumberFormatException` is thrown is this case. If you want to get the values at the time `solve` button is clicked, you have to get the text inside `OnClickListener.onClick` (otherwise you use the initial strings, i.e. the strings in the `android:text` attributes in the `activity_linmotion1` layout). To handle invalid input, you can simply catch the `NumberFormatException`:

```
solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            double time1 = Double.parseDouble(time.getText().toString());
            double acc1 = Double.parseDouble(acc.getText().toString());
            double ivel1 = Double.parseDouble(ivel.getText().toString());
            double fvel1 = Double.parseDouble(fvel.getText().toString());
            double dis1 = Double.parseDouble(dis.getText().toString());

            // ... rest of your original listener code
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             // show error in dialog or something

        }
    }
});
```